# Sequential post processing and plotting with Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop, import, save

I'm trying to do the following:

Import a large data file (something like a 300x50000). Then I need post-process a few of these columns:

1. Take the average of specific columns (eg 3rd, 7th, 18th etc)
2. Save each of these columns with something like CaseX_3rd, CaseX_7th, CaseX_18th)
3. Plot + save the average of each of the CaseX_3rd etc against another vector (some position).

Finally, repeat the above for another Case.

Can anyone suggest some Matlab code to do this? I'm fairly inexperienced with proper workings with Matlab still. This is where I am stuck:

```
% loading files
Case7 = dlmread('Case7.dat', '', 3, 0);

% number of columns that I need data from (no particular sequence..) 
cols = [16, 28, 40, 52, 64, 76, 88, 100]; 

% Generating colum names 
fid = fopen('FNumber.txt', 'wt');
for i = 1:length(cols)
    fprintf(fid, 'FNumber_%d\n', i);
end 

% Reading dat file with colum names 
FNumber = importdata('FNumber.txt'); 

% Trying to assign the column with the name 
% Length of FNumber ought to be the same as column numbers wanted 

% This is where I am properly stuck: 
for i=1:length(cols)
    ith_col = num2str(col(i));
    ith_FNumber = FNumber{i}
    ith_FNumber = Case7(:,i)     % I know this doesn't work, but have no alternative
end 


% The above isn't working, so I'm not going to proceed with the rest of 
% the pseudo-code.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have a much better shot at getting an answer if you post the code you've already tried and why its not working. People on SO don't usually like to write the whole code for someone else...

Comment: In fact, people on SO don't usually like to write the whole code for themselves, either ;-)

Comment: Not trying to get free code...but thanks for the "friendly" suggestion .

Comment: Thanks for posting the code! One thing is, you don't close the file that you wrote to (`'Fnumber.txt'`) before you read it with a different function... I don't know if that could cause problems. The second is, can you explain what "this doesn't work" means? It looks to me like it shouldn't give any syntax errors, so I don't see an immediate problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ith_FNumber = FNumber{i}` will never do anything except assign a value to a variable called `ith_FNumber` - I guess you're trying to create a bunch of differently named variables?

In the first place, you shouldn't be trying to. Things like trying to create a bunch of variables called `CaseX_3rd, CaseX_7th, CaseX_18th` are a bad idea in MATLAB.  You can, technically, do this (using The Function That Must Not Be Named), but there are better ways of handling things. In many cases, this involves using `struct` or `cell` variables.

Say you have a bunch of `'*.dat'`  files in your directory, here's an example using `struct`, and assuming you need the same set of columns for all data:

```
Files = ls('Case*.dat');
cols = [16, 28, 40, 52, 64, 76, 88, 100]; 

for n = 1:size(Files,1);

   % assuming you don't need the rest of the data
   temp = dlmread(Files(n,:), '', 3, 0);

   % just to make it easier to check what's what
   mystruct(n).filename = Files(n,:);

   % we can take all the columns at once
   mystruct(n).data = data(:,cols);

   % mean works along columns by default so we can do this too
   mystruct(n).mean = mean(mystruct(n).data);  

end
```

Then if you need to further process/plot this data you can easily loop over all the data you've imported.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was obvisouly trying to bash a round peg in a square hole. Thanks for your tips. 

Now, why do you suggest that creating variables is not a good idea? I got that from a similar page to: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143-how-do-i-make-a-series-of-variables-a1-a2-a3-a10

I'll study how structures work and your outline should get me started. Many thanks again.

Comment: The way MATLAB is set up, using a struct or cell is infinitely easier if you want to use the same function on multiple sets of data. You can technically create and use multiple named variables, as I alluded to, using a function called `eval`, but even the help file for `eval` has a section "Why Avoid the eval Function?" which points you to using structs and cells instead. (Around here it's also known as `evil`).